# How do you type allocation rule?

Tags: amsmath, cases

I am trying to type this allocation rule in to my latex document

[image]

I can't figure out how would you type it.

Comment: Try with `case` environment.

Comment: @SibaMishra Sorry for your bit error. It is `cases`, instead of `case` :-).

Comment: My bad! Yeah it's the `cases`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a job for the `cases` environment from the `amsmath` package. The following code produces just your desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    \text{if $d\le-0.993$}&\text{allocate to Mandsaur,}\\
    \text{if $-0.993<d<0.657$}&\text{allocate to Chittorgarh,}\\
    \text{otherwise}&\text{allocate to Kota.}\\
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, such usage of `cases` is a bit unconventional. Usually, the alternatives come in the first column, and the conditions in the second one. I would suggest the following code (the result is below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{Allocate to }
  \begin{cases}
    \text{Mandsaur},&\text{if $d\le-0.993$,}\\
    \text{Chittorgarh},&\text{if $-0.993<d<0.657$,}\\
    \text{Kota},&\text{otherwise.}\\
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. I will go with your suggested code.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Always try to provide a `MWE`. That way you will attract more users to answer your questions. Nevertheless, as a starting point you could you use this as a skeleton:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    The allocation is as follows:
    \[\begin{cases}
    \text{if}~a\leq1,&c\\
    \text{if}~b\geq1,&d\\
    c,&e
    \end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]